# Unexpected error while comparing NSdate

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

I am comparing one date (say start_date) with current date (current_date_from_db). But the comparison is failing with either of the two errors:

```
if ([current_date_from_db compare:start_date]== NSOrderedAscending) 
{
     NSLog(@"Yes");
}
else {      
     NSLog(@"No");      
};
```

And

```
while([ current_date_from_db earlierDate:start_date] && [current_date_from_db laterDate:end_date])
```

The code is failing with

> SIGBART: Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString isEqualToDate:]

Comment: One of your objects is not really a date. Somewhere you accidentally assigned a string to a value.

Comment: Make sure you have retained both current_date_from_db and start_date if required. You probably keep a reference to a date that's being auto released, then you try to use it later after it's been changed to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do conversion prior to comparison. Either make an NSDate object with the current_date_from_db or convert the start_date to a string and then compare.

Answer (score 1):

current_date_from_db is a string as you can see in your error message: [NSCFString isEqualToDate:].  You'll want to parse your date and then compare:

```
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:current_date_from_db];
```